# How to use Hadoop and Hive technologies in website to be developed using PHP?

Tags: php, hadoop, hive

I want to build a project where the data's velocity and volume is going to be really large.
So, I'll have to use Big data concepts to implement it.

But I don't know how and where to use them.
Through a lot of research I did install Hadoop and Hive and also got
basic knowledge in Hive but don't know how to proceed.

Can anyone please give me clear cut idea of what Technologies to use where and is it good to use PHP or should I use some other language?

Any input will be helpful.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679800/hive-connection-with-yii

Answer (score 2):

Hive is **not a database**. It's a batch SQL engine over large datasets in HDFS.

Because the data is large is one of the primary reasons it means you should not  expose that data to the user to be loaded by any web application, regardless of the language - the queries take too long to load. And if you are storing data that would be small result sets (for example hundreds MBs - a few GBs), then Hadoop is probably not the place to store data in the first place.

Any query you're expecting to use Hive for, do not expect it to be loaded into a website within any reasonable time period (talking minutes at a minimum). I would be very surprised if any website used Hive as a backend.

Cassandra or HBase should be used to display data to user facing applications. At the very least, you would use Apache Sqoop to export a Hive table into a type of "materialized view" to be seen by users within MySQL/Postgres, which have well established PHP drivers. In other words, start the large data in Hive, manipulate it via some extraction process and load it into a proper database system.

Spark Thrift Server, Drill, or  PrestoDB can be setup for more interactive SQL queries, but again - those should probably be used for adhoc querying, not pulling data quickly  into a website

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Phoenix to run SQL queries in HBase. HIVE and Impala are extremely slow to start up. It's not meant for a websites, it's meant for batch jobs. Apache Phoenix is extremely fast.  You can't use PHP though; use Java. Or use Apache Thrift to run a Java server to query Apache Phoenix, then use the php client version of Thrift to access the data.